# is possible monitor events in html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

I need to know if is  possible monitor events and get results with especific html element like this

click in button "zeta"

or type key in label  "hhh"

Its possible this

Please help me

I use monitor monitorEvents($0) but only get events with  coordinates

Comment: Take a look at [addEventListener()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve with this

```
        $('body').on("click mousedown mouseup focus blur keydown change mouseup click dblclick mousemove mouseover mouseout mousewheel keydown keyup keypress textInput touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel resize scroll zoom focus blur select change submit reset",function(e){
 console.log(e);
      });
```